# defining swift typealiases according to launch arguments

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, type-alias

I'd like to (statically) define a global Swift `typealias` according to launch arguments.

Swift lets me do that with with constants:

```
protocol Client {
}
struct FakeAPIClient: Client {
}
struct ProductionAPIClient: Client {
}

private var isUITesting: Bool {
    return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("UI-TESTING")
}


let APIClient: Client.Type = isUITesting ? FakeAPIClient.self : ProductionAPIClient.self
```

How can I achieve the same thing with typealiases? I'd like to do something like:

```
struct FakeAPIClient {
}
struct ProductionAPIClient {
}

private var isUITesting: Bool {
    return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("UI-TESTING")
}

typealias Client = isUITesting ? FakeAPIClient : ProductionAPIClient
```

But this doesn't compile. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you describing a generic? Of course the details will depend on what you want to _do_ with this dynamically resolved type.

Comment: just call static methods common to `ProductionAPIClient` and `FakeAPIClient`. can that be done with just generics?

Comment: You can't have "static" things defined at runtime. "Static" means that it's defined at compile time. That's the difference between static and dynamic.

Comment: The trouble with your question is that you have not explained what you ultimately want to _do_. As I said, this might be solved by a generic or by protocol adoption, but I don't know _what_ you want to solve.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. The type alias is computed at compile time, when your project is built, while what you're trying to do happens at run time. At run time all type aliases are set in place.

For your use-case of UI testing, a better solution would be to make use of protocols, and instantiate the object you need based on the launch argument:

```
protocol ClientProtocol {
}

struct FakeAPIClient: ClientProtocol {
}

struct ProductionAPIClient: ClientProtocol {
}

func createClient() -> ClientProtocol {
   return isUITesting ? FakeAPIClient() : ProductionAPIClient()
}
```

Instead of using the type alias you'd use the protocol wherever you need in your application.

**Note.** `createClient` is a so called factory function, and can be used in multiple scenarios, not only this one of UI testing. For example you could have an API client based on `AFNetworking` and one based on `NSURLSession` and easily switch between the two with a simple flag change.